# Where to put canonical tag?

Tags: html, seo

I have learned the uses of canonical tag recently. Now, my question is. suppoose i have one master page -

Targeted webpage page - www.example.com/science/medical-science

Another page (clone) - www.example.com/science/medical-science?//586?789

Now suppose these two are basically same webpages, i want all my visitor of link juice to be flown here - http://www.example.com/science/medical-science

So shall i put the "canonical tag" in the source code of the "clone" page ??
like -

Do i need to put any canonical tag here as well - www.example.com/science/medical-science   ???

Please provide the solution as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's preferable not to have the "clone" in the first place, but have the "clone" url redirect to the canonical page instead.

Answer (score 2):

Officially you only need it on the other pages that you want to point to the original page, not on the original page itself.

However it's still a good idea to put it on both pages. Often this is the easiest thing to do because duplicate content usually comes from the same back-end script or code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, I too have seen a lot of websites using "canonical" tag + url of the same page as considered having original or targeted.

Answer (score 0):

Since duplicate pages are often generated from the website's back-end system it's become the standard to just point a canonical link from the page to itself. This way clone pages will also point here.

This will work with your specific case where you have a parameter in the URL. But it will also work for differences like:

**www.example.com VS example.com**

and

**example.com VS example.com/index.html**